# bootstrap 4 col align right with ml-auto

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to align the navigation to the right, but using `.ml-auto` with `.d-flex` is not working and I do not understand why.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Искать по имени" class="form-control">
      </form>
    </div>
    
 <div class="col-lg-9"

        <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Active</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone coming to this question while upgrading from Bootstrap 4 to 5, I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948287/bootstrap-5-navbar-align-items-right (use `ms-auto` instead of `ml-auto` in Bootstrap 5)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you inspect the elements, there's no "empty" space between the columns to add the margin, since both columns are using the full 12 slots; instead you should place the `ml-auto` class in the `ul` element, which is *not* using the full available width, and can be moved inside its parent;

The other option is actually using the flex-utilities that Bootstrap provides to align and justify content inside a flex-container.

**Edit:**
Since what you need is to keep the size of the input; you can set that column to `col-auto`, this will make that column use only the space needed to contain its elements; then in the other column you can use `col` so it uses all the remaining space without having to set an specific amount of slots; finally you can again use the flex utilities like `justify-content-end` on the `ul` element so it sticks to the right side.

There are many options to apply a size to a column, read [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel-form">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Искать по имени" class="form-control">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end flex-nowrap">
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Active</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item pl-4"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how I can do this responsive? Now looks is bad :(

Comment: What do you mean with "responsive"? what behavior do you expect? It is rezising as it should as per Bootstrap standard

Comment: how I can do resize how in stackoverflow on page tags? https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: You are not being clear, what difference do you see on how its resizing on the snippet in comparison to the tags page?

Comment: I need input do not resize, how on stackoverflow. Now your input is resize, and if screen size < 500, then input is small.

Comment: Good, now its clearer, I edited the answer, take a look

Comment: Check please: https://imgur.com/a/BeNBbvp can we do how on stackoverflow? Now navs go on bottom..

Comment: Yes, they go to the bottom because of the size you gave them; if you reduce StackOverflow more they do the same thing; if you don't want them to go to the bottom you can resize them; this goes beyond your original question about aligning the items to the right

Answer (score -1):

Since Bootstrap 4.x already applies Flexbox layout to its Navigational component you need to rely on Flexbox-oriented alignment utilities.  For the described behavior you're asking for you can opt for just a single additional class: `justify-content-end`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a></li>
</ul>
```

Bootstrap 4.x has a lot of different alignment utilities that work best with Flexbox or with more basic placements.  I highly recommend reviewing its documentation for [justifying and aligning Flexbox content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

Comment: But then is not responsive :( I need how In stackoverflow do: https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: You original question did not indicate that responsive behavior was necessary. That being said, `justify-content-*` is subject to responsive breakpoints, which you would know if you had reviewed the documentation I linked.