# Bootstrap 5 navbar align items right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do you align Bootstrap 5 navbar items to the right?  In Bootstrap 3 it's `navbar-right`.  In Bootstrap 4 it's `ml-auto`. But not work for Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 193):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

As of Bootstrap 5 beta, left and right have been replaced by **start** and **end** for [RTL support](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#v500-beta1). Therefore the margin utilities changed for Bootstrap 5 beta:

- `ml-auto` => `ms-auto` (start)
- `mr-auto` => `me-auto` (end)

Also note, *all* uses of left and right have been replaced with **start** and **end** in Bootstrap 5...

- ml-* => ms-*
- pl-* => ps-*
- mr-* => me-*
- pr-* => pe-*
- text-left => text-start
- text-right=> text-end
- float-left => float-start
- float-right=> float-end
- border-left => border-start
- border-right=> border-end
- rounded-left => rounded-start
- rounded-right=> rounded-end
- dropleft => dropstart
- dropright=> dropend
- dropdown-menu-left => dropdown-menu-start
- dropdown-menu-right => dropdown-menu-end
- carousel-item-left => carousel-item-start
- carousel-item-right=> carousel-item-end

---

**Bootstrap 5 alpha (original answer)**

This question was asked for **Bootstrap 5 alpha**, and therefore `ml-auto` should still work.

[How to align nav items to the right in Bootstrap 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253543/align-nav-items-to-right-in-bootstrap-5/65254055#65254055)

Comment: perfect for me - head div for nav-items had to have ms-auto to flex to the end. Lifesaver! God bless you

Comment: This is very helpful as an upgrade guide from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5. A person can just do a site-wide find-replace on all these 

Answer (score 138):

I changed `mr-auto` to `ms-auto` and it worked for me, this is the best solution.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
```

Comment: I'm confused, ms-auto means align to the start (left) but it actually aligns items to the right in my case.... I think I'm taking crazy pills.

Comment: @Francisco When in doubt, look under the hood. `ms-auto` yes means "margin _start_/left auto", but that means "add `margin-left: auto !important;`" which itself is confusing but you can read more about margins here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left#syntax

Comment: Worked for me. Agreed, it doesn't make a lot of sense, I just need it to work.

Answer (score 32):

You need to use `ms-auto` instead of `ml-auto` in bootstrap 5.

Horizontal direction sensitive variables, utilities and mixins are renamed with more logical names — `start` and `end` in lieu of `left` and `right` in **Bootstrap 5**.

- Renamed `.left-*` and `.right-*` to `.start-*` and `.end-*`.
- Renamed `.float-left` and `.float-right` to `.float-start` and `.float-end`.
- Renamed `.border-left` and `.border-right` to `.border-start` and
  `.border-end`.
- Renamed `.rounded-left` and `.rounded-right` to `.rounded-start` and
  `.rounded-end`.
- Renamed `.ml-*` and `.mr-*` to `.ms-*` and `.me-*`.
- Renamed `.pl-*` and `.pr-*` to `.ps-*` and `.pe-*`.
- Renamed `.text-left` and `.text-right` to `.text-start` and `.text-end`.

You can see more bootstrap 5 migration details here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#sass

Answer (score 19):

The justify-content-end class makes the difference.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarResponsive">
```

Comment: This is simple and effective.

Comment: Why only this solution with navbar worked on 5.0.3 alpha?

Answer (score 9):

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65254055)

For more clarification, as per **Bootstrap 5 documentation**, some  utilities are renamed. including left and right.

**left ==> start**

**right ==> end**

therefore

**ml** has changed to **ms**

**mr** has changed to **me**

so right now:

**ml-auto ==> ms-auto**

**mr-auto ==> me-auto**

you can see this [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities-2) in bootstrap documentation

Therefore, if you want your navbar items to be aligned "right", you have to put:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is the same as Bootstrap 4 you should use `ml-auto`. Here is a snippet from. [Navbar Bootstrap 5 offical](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#how-it-works)
And here is the [official home page for Bootstrap 5](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <!-- ml-auto still works just fine-->
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<!--bootstrap 5 -->
<!-- JavaScript and dependencies -->
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js " integrity=" sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo " crossorigin=" anonymous "></script>
<script src=" https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity=" sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/ " crossorigin=" anonymous "></script>
```

### Edit

The question was asked when `bootstrap 5` was in `alpha`. But right now we have `beta` out and they did change the naming to be margin-start and margin-end

> Renamed .ml-* and .mr-* to .ms-* and .me-*

---

> Renamed .pl-* and .pr-* to.ps-* and .pe-*

So the answer should be like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<!--bootstrap 5 -->
<!-- JavaScript and dependencies -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It does not. Please check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer I answered this question when bootstrap was in alpha. I did update the answer to the new version. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This one worked fine for me,

check this out :

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Replace mr-auto with ms-auto

This worked for me, hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can elaborate what such change will do.

Comment: I think you are wrong. mr-auto should be replaced by me-auto. r(right) got replaced by e(end) and l(left) got replaced by s(start).

Answer (score 2):

I gave my `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">` an `#id`. then in css, I used the id to `#navLinks {justify-content:flex-end;}`. Workred fine. Just run the code and do full page.

```css
body {
    background: #f5d9d5;
}

#navLinks { 
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#home, #about, #portfolio, #testimonials {
    margin: 2em 1em 0 1em;
    font-size: large;
}

#brand_name {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 4vh;
}

#bavbar-button {
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <!--Custom CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="KT.css">

    <title>My_portofolio_home</title>
</head>
 
<body>

    <header>

        <!--navbar as a link-->
        <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank" id="brand_name">AI</a>
               <!--toggle_button-->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" id="navbar-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navLinks" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button> 
                <!--navbar options/buttons-->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">                        
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="" id="home">Home</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="about">About</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="KT_portfolio.html" id="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="KT_testimonials.html" id="testimonials">Testimonials</a>                       
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>


    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28310684)

Comment: You're right :( I just started web-development a few days ago and have zero experience on how things work and why. I figured this solution, just by trying out different commands. I'll try and give a more thorough explanation in future posts.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, you can try flex:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex justify-content-end">
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used d-flex for right side alignment

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
         scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="d-flex">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Right link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right link 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"next": "12.1.4",
"node-sass": "^7.0.1",
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.2.3",
"react-dom": "18.0.0"
},

first option

```
<Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav" className="justify-content-end">
        <Nav>
          <Link href="/" passHref>
            <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
          </Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
```

**className="justify-content-end"**

or second option

```
<Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="ms-auto">
          <Link href="/" passHref>
            <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
          </Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
```

**className="ms-auto"**

Answer (score 0):

If the "mb-2" and "mb-lg-0" class is not necessary, simply use the following code, and it should work. Otherwise, you can try adding the "mb-2 mb-lg-0" class to the code.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
```

Here is my Bootstrap 5 Navbar code: - Run Code Snippet

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary navbar-dark" aria-label="Fourth navbar example">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://webziz.in/bmi/">BMI Free Calculator</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-house-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8.707 1.5a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L.646 8.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L8 2.207l6.646 6.647a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293z"></path>
  <path d="m8 3.293 6 6V13.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5V9.293z"></path>
</svg> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://webziz.in/bmi/about-us/">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://webziz.in/bmi/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://webziz.in/bmi/terms-and-conditions/">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?