# What the meaning of Bootstrap 5 class " me-auto "

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

This is bootstrap 5 navbar ul part code.
my problem is:

1. I can't change ul position left to right.
2. what the meaning of bootstrap 5 class "me-auto"

   Home
  Link
  Dropdown
3. Action
4. Another action
5. 
6. Something else here
  Disabled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align nav items to right in Bootstrap 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253543/align-nav-items-to-right-in-bootstrap-5) ... `me-auto` is `margin-right: auto`

Comment: Please [read the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The confusing thing about the new approach is that `ml-auto` & `mr-auto` are replaced with equivalent `ms-auto` & `me-auto`  (which stand for `start` & `end`). If you need to know more about this, search for `css logical properties` and you should find plenty of resources on why they changed these.

Answer (score 17):

Changing `.me-auto` to `.ms-auto` shifts it to the right.

Answer (score 13):

mr-auto => bootstrap 4 margin right-auto

me-auto => bootstrap 5 margin end-auto

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding

Comment: Maybe this deserve a little explanation?

Comment: ms : margin from start (start is left = ml in bootstrap 4). me : margin from end (end is right = mr in bootstrap 4)

Answer (score 6):

me-auto means "margin end auto". Which is actually:

```
margin-right: auto
```

me = margin-right and ms = margin-left

To verify my answer you can download the bootstrap 5.0 here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/

Open css/bootstrap.css file and then search for this className(me-auto) and you will find its css code there.

Answer (score 6):

##### Quick answer

It's the preferable way to make spacings in Bootstrap 5, which is friendly for both LTR and RTL writing systems.

- `me` stands for `margin-end`.
- `me-auto` in LTR is equivalent to `mr-auto` in Bootstrap 4 and before.

##### Details if interested

Spacing classes in Bootstrap 5 are named using the format:

- `{property}{sides}-{size}` for xs,
- `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` for sm, md, lg, xl, and xxl.

Where property is one of:

- m - for classes that set margin
- p - for classes that set padding

Where sides is one of:

- t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
- b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
- **s - (start) for classes that set margin-left or padding-left in LTR, margin-right or padding-right in RTL**
- **e - (end) for classes that set margin-right or padding-right in LTR, margin-left or padding-left in RTL**
- x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
- y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
- blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

Where size is one of:

- 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
- 1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
- 2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
- 3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
- 4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
- 5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
- auto - for classes that set the margin to auto

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding

Answer (score 2):

For ul position left to right use

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-end">
```

me-auto meening bootstrap 5 margin end-auto

Answer (score 1):

ms / me are the Bootstrap 5 "non-directional" versions of ml / mr. By switching to ms / me the start / end is correct when the layout is oriented from right to left (RTL)
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding

```
Bootstrap 4 => Bootstrap 5
ml = margin + left => ms = margin + start
mr = margin + right => me = margin + end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Without seeing code, we can't help about alignment left to right or
   you maybe use.

`float:right` or you can use this CSS:

```
.lefttoright {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
}
```

2. `me-auto` pushing two items to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mr-auto` and `ml-auto` for right and left alignment respectively in Bootstrap 5.

```html
class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.me-auto {
  margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

The code above reveals the CSS rule using Firefox's Developer Tools inspection method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Bootstrap 5**, use **ms-auto** class name to shift the nav links to right. ms-auto stands for margin left auto (s->start). Where as the meaning of **me-auto** is margin right auto (e-> end).

```
<Nav className="ms-auto">
```

I used the same solution and it worked for me.