# How to shift bootsrap 5 navbar li elements to right

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have tried this code but still haven't got signup and login links at right side of page

### I have used mr-auto,ml-auto and even justify-content-end, none of them work

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

   <div class="container-fluid">
     <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">pUpe</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navNav1" aria-controls="navNav1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navNav1">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">log In</a></li>
     </ul>

   </div>
     
</div>


</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting [`ms-auto` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) on the `<ul>` holding "Sign Up" and "Log In".

So change:
`<ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">`

to `<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">`

Apparently in Bootstrap 5 some of the spacing utility names were changed.  `ms-auto` stands for "margin-start: auto".  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65479846/12183520) has a great cheat sheet.

Just a note for the future: to use flex classes like `justify-content-end`, you'll need to use `d-flex` class to make the element a flex item.  But you want the flex element to be the parent of the item you want to align: so above you'd probably want your flex element to be the `<div>` that contains the two navbar elements.