# Install Bootstrap 5 with angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-5, angular13

I have try to install Bootstrap in Angular 13 with this link:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-install-bootstrap-5-in-angular-13example.html

However, as i update bootstrap to v5 it does not work, all the styles are wrong.
On the other hand, it works properly with bootstrap 4.6.1.

I have do the same as this link. Is there another thing that is supose to be done?

Answer (score 0):

my recommendation would be to go to https://getbootstrap.com/ and follow the installation instructions on their website. it has the newest version of bootstrap 5 on it and it gives you links and scripts to input straight into your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's hard to try to import styles only by `npm install`, you'll find that it's much easier to use a CDN instead in most cases.

So what I would suggest you is make `npm uninstall` of any bootstrap package you have listed in your dependencies at `package.json`, then go to `index.html` of your angular project and under the default `<link>s` paste the cdn:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Now your project should have bootstrap 5.

Comment: But if i have no internet will this package work?

Comment: It will not. I assume something you could do is npm install bootstrap, then instead of the https link I pasted there, put a path to the installation in your node_modules folder (it should look like ```"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"```). Or, you could go to your ```style.css``` file and paste the import (something like ```@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";```) .

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that some class names has change from boostrap 4 to boostrap 5. I leave here a link if someone has the same problem:

[Bootstrap 5 navbar align items right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948287/bootstrap-5-navbar-align-items-right)

On the other hand, i installed this library instead boostrap as it has all dependencies and i find it easier

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Answer (score 0):

Its Very Simple you can down my 2 Step into Angular.

- Use Bootstrap Cdn - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/
- Use NPM Command:- npm install bootstrap --save or npm i bootstrap --save.

If you are a new beginner into Angular Please visit my blog on that i have made a Detail content on that page.

Please Visit :- https://ngangulardetails.blogspot.com/p/how-to-install-bootstrap-5-or-latest.html.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32691712)