# How do you align Bootstrap 5 navbar items to the right?

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5, text-align

How do you align Bootstrap 5 navbar items to the right? In Bootstrap 4 it's ml-auto. But not work for Bootstrap 5.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-6">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info ">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">
            <h5>Home</h5><span class="sr-only"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">
            <h5> About</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">
            <h5>Contact me</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948287/bootstrap-5-navbar-align-items-right

Comment: Here you can find more details. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948287/bootstrap-5-navbar-align-items-right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948287/bootstrap-5-navbar-align-items-right)

Comment: Going forward, please use the editor tools available to you to format your code. It wasn't appearing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 no longer use `ml` and `mr` -- instead they swapped it out for `ms` (margin start) and `me` (margin end) to account for RTL support. Obviously in RTL right and left are swapped but start and end still makes sense in this context

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```